# ¿Por qué en Android no existe el método main?

Tags: java, android

Una app de android está construida a partir de componentes como las actividades, por ejemplo, pero la app está escrita en Java, ¿Porque en programas de consola por ejemplo, es necesario tener un método main mientras que en android no y basta con definir un componente principal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad también existe y es usado el método :

```
main(String[])
```

En Android, debido a que la ejecución del código se realiza mediante la Java Virtual Machine,
puedes revisar en la especificación de la Java Virtual Machine:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

en la sección:

"Java Virtual Machine Startup"

indica: La Java Virtual Machine se inicia creando una clase o interfaz inicial usando el cargador de clases de arranque. La Java Virtual Machine luego vincula la clase o interfaz, la inicializa e invoca el método

```
public static method void
main(String[])
```

. La invocación de este método impulsa todas las ejecuciones posteriores. Ejecución de las instrucciones de la Máquina Virtual Java que constituyen el método principal puede causar la vinculación (y en consecuencia la creación) de clases e interfaces adicionales, así como la invocación de métodos adicionales.

Answer (score 0):

En Android el framework se encarga de iniciar el proceso (donde existe un main()) pero eso viene "gratis" al crear la aplicación.

Cuando se inicia tu aplicación, se levanta una nueva instancia de Dalvik y esta busca tu heredada de Activity. Sabe dónde encontrarlo porque en el manifest lo declaras como un LAUNCHER. Por eso busca el método onCreate().

Si quieres más detalles puedes ver este artículo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293329/where-is-main-in-android

Comment: En tu aplicación si se define como Launcher una Activity y se ejecuta el método onCreate() este no tiene que ver con main() o es por la analogía?

Comment: no lo que pasa es que el framework de Android viene con un montón de código que no vez que llamar tu Activity.. pero ese código (que no ves) tiene el main().